# Importing DBF database into SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, dbf

I used the following script for DBF file  migration into SQL server and It runs successfully as well but still I don't Understand What to do with the script?
Where the data gets stored in sql? I mean in which database in sql? Actually, I made the database say 'DB1'in sql server and then made a stored procedure as given below so that my ABC.DBF data get migrated into sql database 'DB1' But nothing has changed. So, can somebody please help me..

Thanks in advance

Query:

```
SELECT * 
INTO ABC
FROM OPENROWSET('VFPOLEDB', 'C:\SomePath\ABC.DBF';'';
                '','SELECT *  FROM ABC'))
```

Comment: The data will be stored *in the current database* in which you're executing this script, and in the `ABC` table.

Comment: Yes, I made the the DB1 database with the 6 colomns in it in which I execute the script but the colomns didn't fill with ABC.DBF values

Comment: Do you get any errors? If so: **what** errors? Does your `SELECT` alone (without the `INTO .....` part) return any data?? Basically, you should **(1)** go to whatever database you want to import the data into, and then **(2)** just run your script - **do NOT** create a table before hand! It will be created by the `SELECT ... INTO ...` statement!